# Apache rewrite to different places

Tags: apache

I have a site:

oldsub.oldsite.com that I now need to rewrite to newsub.newsite.com

So far I have this which seems to work for the site:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName oldsub.oldsite.com
    Redirect 301 / http://newsub.newsite.com
  </VirtualHost>
```

BUT

There is one page that I need to redirect to a different location on the new site.

oldsub.oldsite.com/oldpage now needs to go to newsub.newsite.com/bla/bla/bla/newpage

How do I combine both of these things?
i.e. One specific page gets redirected to the new page on the new site and everything else just goes to the home page of the new site.

Comment: Just place an exception for the more specific URL _before_ the more general "catch all" you already have.

Comment: @arkascha Can you perhaps give an example of what this full vhost would look like then?

Answer (score 0):

Just place an exception for the more specific URL before the more general "catch all" you already have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName oldsub.oldsite.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/oldpage http://newsub.newsite.com/bla/newpage [L,R=301,QSA]

    Redirect 301 / http://newsub.newsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You obviously need the rewrite module inside your http server for that. But it should be available with a single click for all typical distributions.

Comment: Didn't work it seems.

hitting oldsub.oldsite.com/oldpage sent me to this:
newsub.newsite.comoldpage/

Comment: You _did_ reload your http server configuration (restart the deamon)?

Comment: Oh, and disable the clients cache for testing or use an anonymous tab. You probably have a cached attempted that _did_ redirect in the past. `301` is a _permanent_ redirection...

Comment: yip. Did a "service apache2 restart"

Comment: If nothing helps you raise the rewrite log level and check what is actually going on in the rewrite engine.

Comment: Still not. Tried a different pc now and I still get the same strange URL

Comment: Please also post _the exact_ incoming request as shown in the access log file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @arkascha for the advice. Got me in the write direction. This is what worked:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName oldsub.oldsite.com

RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldpage http://newsub.newsite.com/bla/newpage

Redirect 301 / http://newsub.newsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Seems like the rewriterule and redirect don't work well together?

Comment: Wait, still an issue. If I have oldsub.oldsite.com/something it redirects me to newsub.newsite.comsomething, but it should be taking me to just newsub.newsite.com. The oldpage specified in redirectmatch works fine, but anything else doesn't.